# Delete comments from Sharepoint 2010 Scorecard

Tags: performancepoint

I am new to sharepoint, can someone please give me some guidance on how to delete specific scorecard comments in sharepoint?

Is it possible to access the content database to delete the comments directly from the database?
(I have a client that requires comments to be deleted, but a history of the comments needs to be stored in an alternate datastore for possible future reference).

Answer (score 0):

To do this you need to go Central Administration –> PerformancePoint Service Application Settings and then you will see where you can delete comments.

you can also delete the comments from dashboard designer, regardless of where they were entered.

But please please do not delete from content database. Its really bad practice.

Hope it will help.